# Phonegap 2.0.7 > childbrowser DisallowOverscroll

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a phonegap 2.0.7 app with childbrowser plugin.
In my config.xml I have following preference:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

When my page is loaded in childbrowser, I still notice the "rubber band" effect when scrolling.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

in ChildbrowserViewController.m

after webViewDidFinishLoad

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```